# Existe alguma função de Excel que associe letras a números (A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 etc.)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Existe alguma função de Excel que associe letras a números de acordo com a ordem alfabética (ou seja, `f(A) = 1, f(B) = 2, f(C) = 3` e assim por diante)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode usar:

```
CÓDIGO("A") - 64
```

Na versão em inglês:

```
CODE("A") - 64
```

Como o código ASCII de A é 65, vai retornar 1, B vai retornar 2, assim sucessivamente.

Só tome cuidado com letras minúsculas, pois o código é diferente. Se quer uma conversão *case insensitive* precisa converter para maiuscula antes:

```
CÓDIGO(MAIÚSCULA("a")) - 64
```

Na versão em inglês:

```
CODE(UPPER("a")) - 64
```

Veja aplicado no LibreOffice 5, que é compatível:

[image: Screenshot da planilha com a fórmula aplicada]

Comment: Obrigado! Eu conhecia essa função CÓDIGO mas não me lembrava dela.

Comment: Ainda bem que eu não usei o SUM  

Answer (score 3):

Segundo [este artigo](https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-column-letter-to-number) você pode utilizar as funções [COLUMN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/column-function-44e8c754-711c-4df3-9da4-47a55042554b) e [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) em conjunto para pegar o índice numérico de uma string que representa uma coluna.

A função [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) pode receber uma string representando uma célula e retorna uma referência a esta célula.

A função [COLUMN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/column-function-44e8c754-711c-4df3-9da4-47a55042554b) recebe uma referência de uma célula e retorna o índice da coluna.

Então você pode concatenar uma letra qualquer com um número, para ser uma referência de célula válida (ex.: `A` se tornaria `A1`, que é uma referência válida), passar esta string como parâmetro para [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261), que irá converter esta string para uma referência, e passar esta referência para [COLUMN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/column-function-44e8c754-711c-4df3-9da4-47a55042554b) que irá retornar o número desejado.

A vantagem desta abordagem em relação à do Bacco é que funciona também para colunas com mais do que um dígito como `AA` ou `AZ`.

A fórmula ficaria assim<sup>*</sup>:

```
=COLUMN(INDIRECT(letter & "1"))
```

Se o seu Excel é em português, as funções utilizadas devem ser [COL](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/col-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-col-44e8c754-711c-4df3-9da4-47a55042554b) e [INDIRETO](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/indireto-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-indireto-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261). A fórmula ficaria<sup>*</sup>:

```
=COL(INDIRETO(letra & "1"))
```

<sup>* Substitua `letter` e `letra` por uma string (ex.: `"A"` ou `"AA"`) ou por uma referência a uma célula contendo a letra da coluna (ex.: `A2`).</sup>

Print no LibreOffice:

[image: Imagem da fórmula funcionando]

Fonte: [Convert column letter to number (ExcelJet)](https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-column-letter-to-number)